# Get BLE battery level without Gatt

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to show a list of available BLE devices name with battery percentage, is it possible to get battery percentage without GATT connection?

Answer (score 1):

No unfortunately this is not possible unless the remote device has a predefined custom way to expose the battery via something other than GATT (e.g. BLE adverts or L2CAP).

If you are in control of the remote devices, you can always add this information to the advert report. This way, when your Android app scans for remote devices, it can read the battery level that you have added from the advert report.

More info found here:-

- [How BLE Advertisements Work](https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-low-energy-advertisements-part-1/)
- [BLE Advertising Primer](https://www.argenox.com/library/bluetooth-low-energy/ble-advertising-primer/)
- [BLE: It Starts with Advertising](https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-it-starts-with-advertising/)